# Why would video streaming buffer on one monitor but not the other?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, streaming, youtube

Monitor 1: 1920x1080, 120Hz, ASUS VG248

Monitor 2: 1600x900, 60Hz, Spectre E20

When I play a youtube video on my main monitor it will endlessly buffer. If I scroll down to the comments so that only a part of the video is showing it will instantly play until I scroll back up, where it will instantly buffer again.

If I move the same video, at the same quality to my second monitor it plays flawlessly. Move it back and it buffers.

Comment: How are your monitors connected to your PC? are they coming out of the same video card, or is one off the motherboard and the other off a video card?

Comment: @FrankThomas They are both coming through a Dell docking station

Comment: @FrankThomas it does not matter at all. Buffering takes place inside Youtube player. He is not saying that his complete monitor stutters. It is surely not a video card issue

Comment: Buffering of Content occurs in the youtube app, but modern systems use hardware decoding for video, and that is the responsibility of the GPU, as is actually drawing the stream. In Crossfire or other hybrid multi-GPU scenarios, there can be differences in hardware behavior between outputs. Since this has been revealed to be a laptop, it is unlikely that op has multiple video devices, but we don;t know that until we ask.